# iPhone : How to set ImageView's frame in table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I have set imageView's frame in table using the following code.

```
  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ImagePath"]];
  [cell.imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 10, 10)];
```

But image is displayed from the corner of the cell.

It does not changes the position or size.

what should I do ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will not be able to change the cells imageView frame. Your best option would be to create a custom cell.

Comment: Subclassing layoutSubviews is also an option. "Best option" depends on the context. If moving the imageView is the only change required, subclassing may be easier. But when you start customizing the table view cell, it is true that creating a custom cell may be better at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the frame of the cell by creating a subclass of UITableViewCell and overriding the layoutSubviews method.

In your subclass implementation of layoutSubviews, call super's implementation first and then modify the frame of imageView.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208786/positioning-the-imageview-of-a-uitableviewcell.

Answer (score 3):

You can add your desired imageview as a subview to the cell

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"ImagePath"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 10, 10)];
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: although this could possibly work, this will overlay the image on the cells text.

Comment: you can add your own UILabel to the cell which gives you the advantage of customizing your text.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom table view cells and position the elements where you want them to be. 
Its also helpful as you will have control on how similar you want your UI to be be to the requirements.

You can do it in [interface builder](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder) or in [code](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html). Also there are loads of examples as this is most common approach in iphone app development (Having a custom table view cell) and you can use the delegates to populate the table view and it works like a charm.