# UIImageView alignment off in tableview cell on initial showing but not after

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, xcode6

I created a tableview with custom tableviewcells where I have a UIImageView which will hold an image. When the cell is first loaded the image alignment is slightly up too much and a bit to the right. However if I scroll down so that I am unable to see the cell and scroll back up it looks right. I am not moving the UIImageView programaticaly. What am i missing?

This is what it looks like, initial loading on the left and then scroll down and up on the right which is how I want it to look the first time around. And a screenshot of my xib file at the bottom.

[image]

Code in cellForRowAtIndexPath where I set the image looks like this:

```
[tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MainViewTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MainViewTableViewCell"];
MainViewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainViewTableViewCell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[MainViewTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainViewTableViewCell"];
}

Post *post = self.maData[indexPath.row];

cell.titleLabel.text = post.title;
cell.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.descriptionTextView.text = post.descriptionString;
cell.theContent = post.theContent;

UIImage *image = [_imageCache objectForKey:[@(indexPath.row) stringValue]];
if (image == nil) {
    image = [self imageWithImage:post.theImage scaledToSize:cell.imageView.frame.size];
    [_imageCache setObject:image forKey:[@(indexPath.row) stringValue]];
}
cell.imageView.image = image;
return cell;
```

Comment: Debugging the frame before the cellForRowAtIndexPath shows that the UIImageView is positioned correctly at 0,39. So the alignment seems to happen after this for some reason.

Comment: I seem to have found a temporary solution to this problem by overriding the layoutSubviews method and setting the position, the answer can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208786/positioning-the-imageview-of-a-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this tool https://github.com/Flipboard/FLEX to debug your UI, debug the frame of UIImageView. Maybe it will help you in this situation.

Comment: Interesting will give it a try, good to have even if it does not fix my problem :) May halp others who find this issue

Comment: I recommend this tool because we need more information to determine problems. Have some situations: autolayout, contentView, frame, bounds, etc. You should debug all, it will help you find the way to fix that

Comment: The origin of the UIImageview is 15,19 instead of 0,39 but setting the origin after setting the image does not seem to change this.

Comment: You also should check the width of your nib cell, width of your tableView and width screen